# Missing pins of 16F887 in Proteus 8 schematic

Tags: pic, proteus

In schematic of Proteus 8, why pin number 11, 12, 31, 32 of PIC16F887 are missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many CAD systems, power and ground pins on ICs are "hidden" - if you look at the schematic symbol in the symbol editor, you will see the power and ground pins, but they will have a flag that prevents them from appearing on the schematic.

The CAD system will automatically connect all hidden pins having the same net name together, and to any visible net of the same name.

Some designers dislike this feature, and prefer to have all power and ground pins shown.

If using hidden pins, you must carefully check the netlist (and watch when laying out the board) that all hidden are indeed correctly connected.  I was once caught by this feature - my power and ground nets were Vcc and GND, but the MCU used Vss and Vdd, so was not connected to power and ground.  I didn't find this out until I built the board, and the MCU had no power.

Answer (score 2):

These are the power and ground pins, VDD and VSS. How else did you think the IC would get power? I don't know Proteus, but there are likely on a separate logical part of the same device, a separate power block for the schematic capture which allows for putting all the power inputs for an entire schematic in the same place. This avoids the mess of having decoupling caps & power nets cluttering up the signal flow across the schematic.